# IvoryCKEditorBundle Symfony: How to use "ckeditor_widget" from IvoryCKEditorBundle TWIG template in my OWN redefined TWIG template

Tags: forms, symfony, ckeditor, twig, symfony-3.2

I've implemented IvoryCKEditorBundle in my SYMFONY 3.2 project.

I followed the guidelines from [here](https://www.remipoignon.fr/12-symfony-2-editeur-wiziwig-ckeditor-avec-ivoryckeditorbundle) and had an overview of the [doc on the official Symfony site](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/IvoryCKEditorBundle/index.html).

Now I see the following files exits in the IvoryCKEditorBundle directory:

- [my
  project]\vendor\egoloen\ckeditor-bundle\Resources\views\Form\ckeditor_widget.html.twig
- [my
  project]\vendor\egoloen\ckeditor-bundle\Twig\CKEditorExtension.php

And `[my
   project]\vendor\egoloen\ckeditor-bundle\Resources\views\Form\ckeditor_widget.html.twig` defines `{% block ckeditor_widget %}`.

In my projet I have redefined my own template to render a form, using all the tricks given in the [official doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html). And under `[my project]\src\MyBundle\Resources\views`  I have a file `input_inline_template.html.twig` which looks like that:

```
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}
{% use 'CKEditorBundle:Form:ckeditor_widget.html.twig' %}
{% block form_row  %}
   <div    class='col-12'  id={{ id ~ '_div_row_id'}}>
        {% block form_label   %}
         <div class='col-4' id={{ id ~ '_div_label_id' }}>
            {{ parent() }}
          </div>
        {% endblock %}

        {% if form.vars.block_prefixes.2 == "textarea" %}
            {% if (form.vars.block_prefixes.3 is defined) and (form.vars.block_prefixes.3 == "ckeditor") %} 
             {% block ckeditor_widget %}
                 <div class='col-8'>
                  {{ parent() }}
                 </div>
             {% endblock %}
         {% else %}
            {% block textarea_widget %}
                <div class='col-8'>
                  {{ parent() }}
                 </div>
            {% endblock %}
        {% endif %}
     {% endif %}
   </div>
{% endblock %}
```

This does not work. It tells me that it cannot find the `ckeditor_widget` if I don't have the line `{% use 'CKEditorBundle:Form:ckeditor_widget.html.twig' %}` it throws the error:

> Block "ckeditor_widget" on template "form_div_layout.html.twig" does not exist in "form_div_layout.html.twig".

And when the line `{% use 'CKEditorBundle:Form:ckeditor_widget.html.twig' %}` is implemented, it throws an error that is:

> Unable to find template "CKEditorBundle:Form:ckeditor_widget.html.twig"

It tells me it looks for `CKEditorBundle:Form:ckeditor_widget.html.twig` in:
 `[my_symf_project]\app/Resources/views`, `[my_symf_project]\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig/Resources/views/Form`, `[my_symf_project]\vendor\knplabs\knp-menu\src\Knp\Menu/Resources/views`.

**I don't know how to configure in `[my project]\app\config\config.yml` that it should look in `[my project]\vendor\egoloen\ckeditor-bundle\Resources\views\Form\` to find `ckeditor_widget.html.twig`.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [a hint here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/IvoryCKEditorBundle/usage/append-javascript.html).

In `[my project]\src\MyBundle\Resources\views\input_inline_template.html.twig`, I've replaced: `{% use 'CKEditorBundle:Form:ckeditor_widget.html.twig' %}` with: `{% use 'IvoryCKEditorBundle:Form:ckeditor_widget.html.twig'  %}`.

It fixed it.